# wftool.doActionFor does not trigger a content rule

Tags: plone

I have setup a content rule that gets triggered when I change the state of a dexterity object through the web interface, but when I change the state programmatically the content rule is not triggered.

I use the typical workflow_tool.doActionFor for changing the review_state. The review_state in the catalog/object  appears changed to the new state.

Any clues??

I'm using plone 4.2.5 and dexterity 1.2.1.

This is the code I use to change the state:

```
cart = brains[0].getObject()
wftool = getToolByName(self.context, 'portal_workflow')
wftool.doActionFor(cart, 'charge')
wftool.doActionFor(cart, 'pay')
modified(cart)
```

Comment: Works fine for me in Plone 4.3. What versions of Plone, Dexterity, etc. are you using? Please edit your question with those details.

Comment: Sounds like you need to check what Zope 3 events doActionFor fire sand what events content rule listens to. There might be need to trigger this event manually.

Comment: @oggers Works fine for me with Plone 4.2.5 and Dexterity 1.2.1 too. I call `doActionFor` from a browser view - are you doing the same? Please explain more about your setup. The more details you add to your question, the likelier you are to get a useful answer.

Comment: Can you show us the code you use, to change the state programatically?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out that triggering only one transition at a time, plone fires the content rule as expected.

Therefore in my case I setup a workaround in the following way:

The states are: **created** -> **charged** -> **paid**, and the content rule fires when changing to state **paid**. Sometimes I must change the state from **created** to **paid** in one transaction. I enabled the **pay** transition from state **created** bypassing the intermediate state **charged**. So, I only need to trigger one transition to **pay** a **created** object, and the content rule works.